# What are the Chrome command line switches / parameters?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Where can I find a list of command line switches to use with Chrome and chromedriver?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- For Chromium find a list here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc
- or (in a more readable format) here: http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Comment: @poolie then what are? ...and where can I find a list of them?

Comment: @nolsen311 just go to chrome://flags/ in your Chrome browser

Comment: `chrome://flags` doesn't seem to have anything to do with the command-line.

Comment: Worth noting: the "readable" version at peter.sh is automatically updated daily to stay in sync with the source code (chrome_switches.cc).

Comment: He asked for chrome, not chromium.

Comment: FYI: `chrome_switches.cc` is no longer (since like 2012) the definitive list of switches in chrome. [There are many other files that define switches](https://cs.chromium.org/search/?q=_switches.cc&sq=package:chromium&type=cs)