# Can someone share the complete list of arguments that one can pass in options.addArguments()?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have used the following based upon issues/requirements faced:

**ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();**

```
       1. options.addArguments("--**start-maximized**");
       2.options.addArguments("--**disable-web-security**");
       3. options.addArguments("--**no-proxy-server**");
       4. options.addArguments("--**disable-extensions**");
       5.options.addArguments("--**disable-infobars**");
```

So i want to know what else arguments we can pass?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136212/what-are-the-chrome-command-line-switches-parameters#21136213

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the Chrome command line switches / parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21136212/what-are-the-chrome-command-line-switches-parameters)

Comment: I can provide you the list I normally work with but as a good practice you should be using the options as per your requirement to keep your code minimum and simple. Moreover​ options class parameters are different for Chrome, Firefox & IE.  Can you let me know your exact requirement to achieve through options class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the list of commands for chrome
https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Answer (score 1):

For the complete list of Chrome Driver arguments, Refer  http://www.assertselenium.com/java/list-of-chrome-driver-command-line-arguments/

Comment: That's a list from July 12, 2015.

Comment: @MarkLapierre Is there a possibility that some of the supported options be dropped in the recent releases?

Comment: @Dev The chrome team probably wouldn't want to remove options, although it's possible, but new ones might be added.